# C# / WPF: Binding TabControl - TabItem (Name) to HeaderedContentControl - Header

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a HeaderedContentControl in my application. In this HeaderedContentControl there is a TabControl.
Now I want to display the name of the selected tab (TabItem) in the header of the HeaderedContentControl (like in Visual Studio the Solution Explorer / Team Explorer e.g.).
My application is (partly) based on [Josh Smiths WPF-MVVM-Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) but I use additional Prism with Unity.
Furthermore I split the resources in some files.

Here is my MainView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="STController.ModuleAComport.View.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300">


<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Resources\MainViewResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>

    </Grid.Resources>


    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}">


        <HeaderedContentControl Header="?"
            Style="{StaticResource MainHeadreredContentControlStyle}"
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
                                Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is my MainViewResources.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:view="clr-namespace:STController.ModuleAComport.View"
                xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:STController.ModuleAComport.ViewModel">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/STController.Resources;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- Put your not shared resource here -->

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:ComportViewModel}">
    <view:ComportView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:TestViewModel}">
    <view:TestView />
</DataTemplate>


<DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />        
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>


<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
                Style="{StaticResource MainTabControlStyle}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                Margin="4"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MainTabItemStyle}">
    </TabControl>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I had two different solution approaches:

1) Binding the SelectedIndex:
My first idea was to bind the SelectedIndex of the TabControl to a property in my viewmodel.
With the index I can then "select" the related view (viewmodel) and get the name and bind it to the header (see HeaderedContentControl; Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"; Workspaces is of type ObservableCollection)
But once I bind the SelectedIndex property of the TabControl, the TabControl does not switch reliable anymore. Sometimes when I click on the TabItem it is switching sometimes not. Sometimes I need to click ten or more times. A very strange behavior. There is no difference if I implement the property (SelectedIndex) in my viewmodel or not.

2) Elementbinding:
My second idea was to implement a ElementName-Binding
But as I expected this does not work (Visual / Logical Tree). The error is:

```
"Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=TabControl'. 
BindingExpression:Path=ActualHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 
'HeaderedContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Header' (type 
'Object')"
```

In this case I also tried to move the TabControl into the Resources of the UserControl and Grid.

So the question is: Is it possible / how is it possible to show the name of the selected tab of the TabControl in the header of the HeaderedContentControl?
Is there a solution without code behind (I don't really like code behind ;) )?

Comment: This is all UI concern, and so shouldn't go in any view model.  Code behind is where you put code dealing with UI concerns.

Comment: @Will Can you give me a hint on how to do this?

Comment: @Will I tried to bind the Header like this: `Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=MyText}"` and the TabControl: `SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="DisplayName">` In the Code-Behind I also added a property. But the Header does not refresh when the Tab is changed. Another problem is that the TabControl shows nothing when I start my application.